# Bot Framework v4 Node: How to use userState in a base class

Tags: node.js, botframework

For a multi language bot running on Messenger I need to store the current language of the user in botState. This works fine for most components:

In Index.js the userState instance is created and passed to the main dialog

```
const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);
const dialog = new RequestProcessing(userState);
const bot = new DialogBot(conversationState, userState, dialog);
```

From within the main dialog, I am able to create accessors and pass userState to my componentdialogs

```
    constructor(userState) {
        super(LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG);
        this.userState = userState;
        this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE);
        this.addDialog(new LeadCaptureDialog(userState));
```

Using userState in my dialogcomponents works perfectly like this.

However:  I am also using a base class called CancelAndHelpDialog ([based on this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/cancelAndHelpDialog.js) ) to handle interrupts like cancel and help in my componentdialogs.

I don't know how to pass userState to this base class.

Any guidance is much appreciated

Comment: So I'm guessing when you call `super` in your constructor it goes straight to the component dialog constructor because your cancel and help dialog doesn't have a constructor. But why not just give it a constructor?

Comment: Exactly the type of guidance I needed. Thanks. I already had the constructor but just added userState to it. For some reason it just accepts it)  Don't understand why but it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already know how to make the user state a parameter of your main dialog's constructor. You can do the same in your cancel and help dialog's constructor, and pass the user state to it when you call `super`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: Thanks. What I still don't get is this: I have this class LeadCaptureDialog extending CancelAndHelpDialog class. In LeadCaptureDialog I have userState in my constructor (passed from my mainDialog.) In the constructor of LeadCaptureDialog I call super ('LeadCaptureDialog'). In CancelAndHelpDialog I have a constructor accepting two parameters: (id, userState) I would expect that I have to 'pass' the userState from LeadCaptureDialog to CancelAndHelpDialog via super('LeadCaptureDialog', userState) but I don't have to. Super('LeadCaptureDialog') also does the trick. Why?

Comment: There's no way for me to know that without seeing the relevant code. If you can't figure it out then you might want to post that as a new question. Try stepping through your code to see what values get populated when, like seeing if the user state is actually passed to the CancelAndHelpDialog's constructor when you call `super` or if the user state got into the CancelAndHelpDialog some other way.

Comment: Ok, did some additional logging. Seems it was caused by some kind of child -> parent inheritance caused by the adding of the constructor. I have written an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kyle's answer. The following approach worked for me.

My componentdialog extends a base class:

```
class LeadCaptureDialog extends CancelAndHelpDialog { ...
```

The constructor of the LeadCaptureDialog class accepts userState and create an accessor to access the userState

```
    constructor(userState) {
            super(LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG);
            this.userState = userState;
            this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE);
            ...
    }
```

In CancelAndHelpDialog class I added a constructor

```
    constructor(id) {
        super(id); 
        ...
{
```

With this approach I am able to access userState in this class by using

```
const userProfile = await this.userProfileAccessor.get(stepContext.context, { language: 'fr' });
```

I did not know you can access child objects from the parent class.